# Read and write in multiple file based on external text inputs

Tags: java, html, text, gis

I am looking for a way to write multiple text file based on external text inputs in specific way. Currently I am able to write external text data in single txt file in desired format using Java but I need to write text in separate file based on GIS values. It means all tables will be in single file if GIS is common with filename as GIS and will further split as per GIS name.

My external data having more than 50000 values which is not possible manual. Please suggest if this is possible in any other way using Perl, shell, PHP script.

Requirement to write in separate files like:

A. BAB.txt : GIS is common here..

```html
 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHOPAL</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>BAB-H1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>BAB</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>BAB-H1</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHOPAL</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>BAB-H2</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>BAB</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>BAB-H2</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHOPAL</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>BAB-H3</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>BAB</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>BAB-H3</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>
```

B. RAH.txt :

```html
 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHILAI</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>RAH-A1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>RAH</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>RAH-A1</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHILAI</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>RAH-A2</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>RAH</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>RAH-A2</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>
```

My external inputs from text file :

> ```
> City,Link,Node Name,GIS
> BHILAI,RAH-A1,RAH-A1,RAH
> BHILAI,RAH-A2,RAH-A2,RAH
> BHILAI,COMBO,RCV-A1,RCV
> BHILAI,COMBO,RIA-A1,RIA
> BHILAI,MPCG_ALU,RJA-A1,RJA
> BHILAI,MPCG_ALU,RJP-A2,RJP
> BHILAI,MPCG_ALU,RKU-A1,RKU
> BHILAI,COMBO,RNN-A1,RNN
> Bhilai,RNN-A4,RNN-A4,RNN
> BHOPAL,BAB-H1,BAB-H1,BAB
> BHOPAL,BAB-H2,BAB-H2,BAB
> BHOPAL,BAB-H3,BAB-H3,BAB
> BHOPAL,COMBO,BAB-H4,BAB
> BHOPAL,COMBO,BAB-H5,BAB
> ```

Java output: Currently writing in single file

```html
 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHILAI</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>RAH-A1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>RAH</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>RAH-A1</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHILAI</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>RAH-A2</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>RAH</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>RAH-A2</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHILAI</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>RCV-A1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>RCV</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>COMBO</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>

 <TABLE>
   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>BHILAI</b></TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>RIA-A1</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>RIA</TD></TR>
   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>COMBO</TD></TR>
 </TABLE>
```

Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class MakeTestCfg_CM
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("table.txt");
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
            String line = null;
            String city = null;
            String link = null;
            String nodename = null;
            String gis = null;

            while (( line = input.readLine()) != null)
                {
                StringTokenizer strT = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
                    city = strT.nextToken();
                    link = strT.nextToken();
                    nodename = strT.nextToken();
                    gis = strT.nextToken();
                    out.println(" <TABLE>");
                    out.println("   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>"+city+"</b></TD></TR>");
                    out.println("   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>"+nodename+"</TD></TR>");
                    out.println("   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>"+gis+"</TD></TR>");
                    out.println("   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>"+link+"</TD></TR>");
                    out.println(" </TABLE>");
                    out.println();
                }
                input.close();
                out.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Java & Javascript are separate languages, and Java is **not** a scripting language.

Comment: Unable to understand reason for devote? There is no debate whether my question related with Java or JavaScript, I may be wrong here.. but I am looking for solution of my requirement.

Comment: *"Unable to understand reason for devote?"* DYM the down vote? If so, you'd have to ask the person that down voted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the actual amount of content within the supplied data file I think the easiest way to go about this is sequentially.

Process one data line at a time within a **loop** and with each line:

1. Read in a data line (ignore first line since it's a Header Line);
2. Split the data line into a string array;
3. Determine the required file name (ie: GIS + ".txt");
4. Does the file already exist? If not create it;
5. Place the string array data elements into a HTML string template;
6. Write the HTML template string to the GIS determined file;
7. Process next data file line (loop - Start from #1 again) .

The runnable code below basically does exactly this:

```
package maketestcfg_cm;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MakeTestCfg_CM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String suppliedDataFile = args[0];
        if (suppliedDataFile.isEmpty() || suppliedDataFile.equals("")) {
            return;
        }

        // Variable to hold the actual System line separator
        String ls = System.lineSeparator();
        // A html template used to write to files in a single write.
        // Note we use tags instead of variables. These tags are 
        // replaced when we write to whichever file. The tags are:
        // %c% = City | %l% = Link | %n% = Node Name | %g% = GIS
        String htmlTemplate = " <TABLE>" + ls + 
                              "   <TR><TD>City:</TD><TD><b>%c%</b></TD></TR>" + ls +
                              "   <TR><TD>Node Name:</TD><TD>%n%</TD></TR>" + ls + 
                              "   <TR><TD>GIS:</TD><TD>%g%</TD></TR>" + ls + 
                              "   <TR><TD>Link:</TD><TD>%l%</TD></TR>" + ls +
                              " </TABLE>" + ls + ls;

        try {
            // Prepare to read the data file.
            // Place each line in the data file into a ArrayList.
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            int counter = 0;
            try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(suppliedDataFile))) {
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Ignore lines that contain nothing and ignore
                    // the first line which is a CSV header line.
                    line = line.trim();
                    if (line.equals("") || counter == 0) {
                        counter++;
                        continue;
                    }
                    list.add(line);
                }
            }

            // Each data file line is now contained within a 
            // List interface named 'list'. Now we process
            // each line (List element):
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                // Parse the current line into a String Array
                String[] City_Link_NodeName_GIS = list.get(i).split(",");
                // Get the GIS & trim off leading/trailing spaces (if any).
                String gis = City_Link_NodeName_GIS[3].trim();
                // Create the file name
                String currentFileName = gis + ".txt";
                File file = new File(currentFileName);
                // if file doesnt exists, then create it
                if (!file.exists()) {
                    file.createNewFile();
                }

                // Append to file...
                try ( FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(), true); 
                      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw)) {
                      // Here we replace the tags in template 
                      // with proper values. Notice that all element
                      // data is trimmed of leading/trailing whitespace
                      // (just in case).
                      bw.write(htmlTemplate.
                            replace("%c%", City_Link_NodeName_GIS[0].trim()).
                            replace("%n%", City_Link_NodeName_GIS[2].trim()).
                            replace("%g%", City_Link_NodeName_GIS[3].trim()).
                            replace("%l%", City_Link_NodeName_GIS[1].trim()));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MakeTestCfg_CM.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MakeTestCfg_CM.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The reader and writers in the code above are automatically closed because [**Try-With-Resources**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) is used. This feature was only make available in **Java 7+**.

Comment: Hello DevilsHnd thanks for update. Unfortunately I am unable to run this code due to multiple errors which I am trying to fix. I am new in java so taking time.

Comment: What are the errors? The code provided was tested and functions properly.

Comment: Hello DevilsHnd I am getting multiple errors while compiling class file using javac. Here I need some guidance to run this code.

Comment: Run the code within your Java IDE until you can figure out how to use javac.exe and java.exe.

Comment: The errors you are getting is most likely because of the [Try-With-Resouces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statements used within the code. This feature is only available in Java 7+. You are most likely compiling with Java 6-. Download and install Java 8 then compile with the newer JDK (1.8.0.xxx) and your errors should go away.

Comment: Hello DevilsHnd. Thanks for your suggestions. I will check and will get back to you.

Comment: Hello DevilsHnd, it is working perfectly. Issue was with Java version only. Thanks for your help.